# wii remote plus library

Tags: wiimote

is there a library (C# or C++) that support the new wii remote plus?
 
In particular to access the angular data.
I managed to get the acceleration data, but using the same program as with the wii motion plus doesn't work for the angular data...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you, However, the new Wii Remote Plus controller is different from the old one. There is no need to attach the wii motion plus, instead it is assembled together from scratch. That's the reason that make me wonder if there's any problem regarding hardware addresses and so on that work with old Wii Remote + Wii Motion Plus but no longer works with the new Wii Remote Plus. Can you give me any updates about this? Regards from Spain.

Answer (score 0):

the 1.8 beta version of the wiimotelib supports the motion plus extension, see  http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

i know maybe it's too late but i modified the bryan peek's lib to accept the new wiimoteplus: it's about the implement the new product id:

Name         Nintendo RVL-CNT-01    Nintendo RVL-CNT-01-TR (wiimote plus)
Vendor ID    0x057e         0x057e
Product ID   0x0306         **0x0330**

source: **http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote**

so, all you need to do is modify the PID const on Wiimote.cs to use the new **0x0330**